# Is there a way to pass 'std::vector 2d' as a pointer to '2d c array' to a function

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way to pass 'std::vector 2d' as a pointer to '2d c array' to a function.

I know you can pass std::vector 1d as a pointer to c array to some function. 
for example,
function:

```
void foo(char* str); //requires the size of str to be 100 chars

std::vector<char> str_;
str_.resize(100);
foo(&str_[0]); //works
```

I'm wondering if it is possible for 2d vectors too like for 
function

```
void foo(char** arr_2d);
```

and vector

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> vector_2d;
```

I tried the following code but im getting some error related to heap corruption.

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> vector_2d;
//assuming function expects the size of the vector to be 10x10  
vector_2d.resize(10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    vector_2d[i].resize(10);
}
foo(&vector_2d[0]);//error here
```

Comment: Okay, now *finally* after all those edits your question makes some sense.

Comment: BTW, `char**` is used with an array of arrays, not a 2-D array

Comment: Can't do it directly, sorry. You have to build an array of pointers from your vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
std::vector< std::vector<unsigned char> > vector_2d;
vector_2d.resize(10);
std::vector<unsigned char*> ptrs(vector_2d.size());
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    vector_2d[i].resize(10);
    ptrs[i] = &vector_2d[i][0];
}
foo(&ptrs[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. The reason is that `char**` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`, but `&vector_2d[0]` is of type `std::vector<char>*`.

I would recommend that you change the interface of the function to take your bidimensional vector (which you might want to redesign to be a class holding a single `std::vector<char>` and providing `operator()(int x,int y)` to access element `(x,y)` in the buffer. Alternatively, you can create the needed data structure on demand:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > data2d;
std::vector<char *> iface_adapter;
iface_adapter.reserve(data2d.size());
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < data2d.size(); ++i ) {
   iface_adapter.push_back( &data2d[i][0] );
}
foo( &iface_adapter[0] );
```

Comment: @MattPhillips: That was a mistake in the question. I edited that.

Comment: that wasnt a mistake..i get error before the function call..right where i had error here comment before @JesseGood

Comment: yea it works for me too now.. before i was getting some heap corruption error.the solution posted by ben works for me @JesseGood